# LinearLayout gives an error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have a problem. I was trying to create an app, but I get an error and I really have no idea how to fix it. It gives a red cross before EditText, and I think it has to do with how everything is opened/closed, but I just can't find a problem.

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />



    />
```

Would like to hear from you.

Comment: Missing `>` at end of first `LinearLayout` tag. And the end tag should be `</LinearLayout>` instead of just `/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your problem

you left the `>` closing sign on your linear layout.

this is the right way

```
   <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <!--items go here  -->
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout should have an open and close tag:

```
<LinearLayout
   attributes here...>
....stuf there...
</LinearLayout>
```